# To change from Hybrid Application to Native Application

Tags: android, cordova, authentication, native, phonegap-build

I've an android application which was done in hybrid(PhoneGap) coding. Now I've did the same application in android native coding. The application has user login sessions. 
In my hybrid coding the logged in user details are stored in a local database using SQL. While in native coding I've saved the user details in SharedPreferences. 
Now If I update my application in playstore from hybrid one to native, I believe the user will be asked to login once again. But I don't the users to be asked for login details again. It means even if the user updates the application and changes from Hybrid one to native, the user session should remain the same. 
Therefore can anyone help me how I can achieve this or is this possible to do???

Comment: Open the SQLite database, if exist; read the values and store it in your SharedPreferences. Delete the database.

Comment: I've a doubt here, would the SQLite db exists after the application is updated???

Comment: I have no experience with hybrid apps, but if you upgrade a native app, the databases still exist after the update. Otherwise all your data will be lost after each app update.